# Gas Fireplace pilot light stays on but the main burner won't start

Tags: gas, fireplace

I have a Superior DR-500CMN direct vent gas fireplace that won't start. I have cleaned the Thermocouple and Thermopile. The pilot light stays on strong and has a clean blue flame. I tested the Thermopile and it was around 545mV, so that seems OK. I have tried to bypass the switch by manually connecting the two wires on the switch and also tried jumping the TH and TP/H terminals with a paper clip, yet the main burner still doesn't turn on. Does anyone have any other ideas before I resort to calling a tech to come out and look at it?

[image: Here is the Pilot Assembly I have]

Answer (score 1):

After testing the Thermocouple and also getting solid readings, I decided it must be a bad gas valve. Since Honeywell doesn't make gas valves anymore I got the closest replacement online that I could find (0820652 Sit 820 Nova Natural Gas valve). It wasn't a direct replacement, I hade to alter the original bracket to make it fit, flip the gas valve and reroute everything to the opposite side but it's working great now.

Comment: Are you the same person as Weldon who posted the original question? If so, thanks for coming back to answer your question! Please follow the [instructions here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to get the accounts merged. If not, please clarify how this answer applies to the original question.

Comment: I am the same person, I submitted a request to merge the account as you suggested. Thanks.